# pandas index_col="datetime" makes df['datetime'] unavailable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

The title says it all.
The following bit of pseudo-code returns the following error:

```py
df = pd.read_sql(query, conn, parse_dates=["datetime"],
                             index_col="datetime")
df['datetime']
```

I get :

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\admin\.virtualenvs\EnkiForex-ey09TNOL\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2656, in get_loc
     return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 108, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
   File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 132, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
   File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1601, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
   File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1608, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
 KeyError: 'datetime'
```

Am I misunderstanding what's going on by indexing the `datetime` col? I can access all the other columns normally though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An index is not a column. Think of the index as [labels for the rows](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#selection-by-label) of the DataFrame. `index_col='datetime'` makes the datetime column (in the csv) the index of `df`. To access the index, use `df.index`.

Comment: I was gonna say that too, nice +1

Comment: Thanks for this. for some reason this explanation made it tick in my mind. I get it now.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

time = pd.date_range(end='4/5/2018',periods=2)
df.index = time
df.index
```

the end is `DatetimeIndex(['2018-04-04', '2018-04-05'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')`
just use df.index can get the information of the index_col